# Why doesn't netty use AsynchronousServerSocketChannel directly?

Tags: netty, nio

It seems like netty uses nio `ServerSocketChannel` with selectors internally to implement async sockets apps.

Why hasn't netty directly used `AsynchronousServerSocketChannel`?

Comment: It didn't exist when Netty was first designed.

Comment: Why not migrate now, it's a better event-driven architecture, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netty supported it at some point but it did not give an advantages. These days netty also supports native transports for epoll / queue which uses JNI directly. These are the ones with the best performance and usually used in production.